# Scala/Spark join on a second key if the first key doesn't exist in one of the dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:

```
 RegionValues:
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|marketplace|primary_id|values                |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|xyz        |0000000001|[cat, dog, cow]       |
|reg        |PRT0000001|[hippo, dragon, moose]|
|asz        |0000001333|[mouse, rhino, lion]  |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+

Marketplace:
 
+----------+-----------+----------+
|primary_id|marketplace|parent_id |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|0000000001|xyz        |PRT0000001|
|0000000002|wrt        |PRT0000001|
|PRT0000001|reg        |PRT0000001|
|PRT00MISS0|asz        |PRT00MISS0|
|000000000B|823        |PRT0000002|
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

when I join the dataframes together I want to join them based on the `primary_id` value but if the `primary_id` field is not present in the `RegionValues` dataframe, then I want to fallback to joining on `parent_id` === `primary_id`. So my desired output would be:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
|primary_id|marketplace   |parent_id  |values                               |
+----------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
|0000000001|...           |PRT0000001 |[cat, dog, cow]                      |
|0000000002|...           |PRT0000001 |[hippo, dragon, moose]               |
|PRT0000001|...           |PRT0000001 |[hippo, dragon, moose]               |
|PRT00MISS0|              |PRT00MISS0 |null                                 |
|0000001333|              |0000001333 |[mouse, rhino, lion]                 |
|000000000B|              |PRT0000002 |null                                 |
+----------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

note that `0000000001` maintained its original `values` but that `0000000002` took on its parent_id's `values` since its not present in `RegionValues`. Is it possible to accomplish this logic within a join statement? I am using Scala and Spark.

I have tried to use a join statement like this but this results in a null value for the `0000000002` values:

```scala
val parentIdJoinCondition = when(
    (regionValuesDf.col("primary_id") === marketplaceDf.col("primary_id")).isNull,
    marketplaceDf.col("parent_id") === regionValuesDf.col("primary_id")
  ).otherwise(regionValuesDf.col("primary_id") === marketplaceDf.col("primary_id"))

val joinedDf = regionDf.join(
    marketplaceDf,
    parentIdJoinCondition,
    "outer"
)
```

I think I could get my desired result by using 3 distinct joins but this seems unnecessary and harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating custom conditions will result to Spark performing a cross-join, that is a very inefficient way to join. Moreover, there is no way for Spark to know that a column does not match before performing actual join, so your condition `regionValuesDf.col("primary_id") === marketplaceDf.col("primary_id")).isNull` will always return false.

So, as you correctly guessed, the best solution is to perform several joins. You can end with two joins. First join to determine if we should use `primary_id` or `parent_id` value for outer join, and the actual outer join. Then, you can merge `primary_id`, `marketplace` and `parent_id` and drop useless columns

So the code would be:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, col, when}

val joinedDf = marketplaceDf.join(regionDf.drop("marketPlace"), Seq("primary_id"), "left")
  .withColumn("join_key", when(col("values").isNotNull, col("primary_id")).otherwise(col("parent_id")))
  .drop("values")
  .join(
    regionDf
      .withColumnRenamed("primary_id", "join_key")
      .withColumnRenamed("marketplace", "region_marketplace"),
    Seq("join_key"),
    "outer"
  )
  .withColumn("primary_id", coalesce(col("primary_id"), col("join_key")))
  .withColumn("parent_id", coalesce(col("parent_id"), col("join_key")))
  .withColumn("marketplace", coalesce(col("marketplace"), col("region_marketplace")))
  .drop("join_key", "region_marketplace")
```

That gives you the following `joinDf` dataframe:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|primary_id|marketplace|parent_id |values                |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|0000000001|xyz        |PRT0000001|[cat, dog, cow]       |
|0000001333|asz        |0000001333|[mouse, rhino, lion]  |
|0000000002|wrt        |PRT0000001|[hippo, dragon, moose]|
|PRT0000001|reg        |PRT0000001|[hippo, dragon, moose]|
|000000000B|823        |PRT0000002|null                  |
|PRT00MISS0|asz        |PRT00MISS0|null                  |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `regionValuesDf.col("primary_id") =!= marketplaceDf.col("primary_id"))` instead of `regionValuesDf.col("primary_id") === marketplaceDf.col("primary_id")).isNull` in your join statement help ?